# Is it feasible to develop in Android what would be an equivalent of logcat output in little time?

Tags: android, logcat

The question may sound stupid, but I'm explaining:

I'm not 100% sure how logcat Works, but I think it's safe to guess that it reads internal produced messages from the app it's monitoring.

I think it would be possible to also get to read these messages in the way that logcat "would be added" to the app and it would be possible for example to put a thread that would search patterns in that "logcat added to the app" and produce some action, same way a developer searchs for certain patterns to make the app work. This way it would be possible to get a detailed log of what have been the actions of an user that may cause an error in the app for example, withouth the need of having to plug the pone in the computer and trying to reproduce the error.

But maybe logcat is something extremely complex on its own, and what I'm saying is total nonsense for any practical purpose.

Is it feasible what I'm mentioning?

Answer (score 1):

logcat is reading stack traces.  You can place your project inside a try and in the catch, redirect the stack trace to a database or whatever.  In our project, we have Acralyzer added as a dependency and it sends all errors to our server.  Note that we aren't using that horrid CouchDB-we are custom-parsing the json ourselves.  We do this on deployed apps so we have a stack trace of exactly what line in the program failed.  This is almost always enough information.  "null reference" is pretty explanatory for example.